# How to emulate 'git stash' in fossil, bzr?

Tags: bazaar, git-stash, fossil

Is it possible to emulate the behavior of 'git stash' when using fossil/bzr?

Basically I'm interested in handling the following workflow:

- at some point the source code tree has state X, it is commited
- I proceed to writing new code, I write it for a while and I see the
  opportunity of a refactoring
- I can't commit at this point, because the change I've started to make is not
  completed, it is not atomic yet
- at this point I would do 'git stash', would save the current work and would
  get back to state X
- I would do the refactoring and commit, source code now has state Y
- I would merge source code in state Y with code in stash, complete the change
  to make it atomic, then commit once again, pushing the source code to state Z

I think that generally it is possible to emulate this scenario when using
another SCM by branching the code in state X instead of doing 'git stash',
doing the refactoring in that branch, then merging the branch back into the
main one. But I'm aware that branching is not always a cheap operation. So are
there any better particular approaches that eventually rely on specific
features of fossil/bzr?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `bzr shelve` and `bzr unshelve` commands.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `patch` command of your system.

- First you make a "stash" by storing a generated diff as .patch file:

  `$scmtool diff > working.patch`
- then reset your working directory.
- later, apply the patch with:

  `patch -p1 --dry-run < working.patch`
- and then this works, remove the `--dry-run` to apply the patch for real.

Comment: The question was about bzr, not git!

Comment: @Randal - You're missing the point. vdboor has lowered the requirements from needing a stash/shelve feature to needing a diff feature in the SCM. This'll work with anything, and now the 'fossil' part of the OP has been answered.

Comment: @teepark thank you for your support, I've updated the post to make this more obvious

Answer (score 8):

The `stash` command was implemented in fossil recently. You got to check out latest fossil executable you will see `stash` in the available command list.

Here is the link to the [web help on its syntax](http://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=stash).

Comment: I use `fossil stash` quite extensively. No complaints, none at all.